# Level, even, flat, smooth

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-difference

According to my dictionary (Webster's):

> A **level** surface is one that is flat and even
>   A **smooth** surface is one with no rough parts or bumps
>   A **flat** surface is one that is smooth, level, or even

I searched a lot but the websites didn't really give me a full understanding as to how these words are exactly different.  What I learned from the sources here and there is:

> A **level** surface has no slope
>   A **smooth** surface has no rough parts
>   A **flat** slope has no curves or bumps and no slope

I'd like to know if my deduction is correct.  Here are more questions:

1. Can a surface be **flat** but *not* **level**?
2. Can a surface be **smooth** but *not* **level**?
3. Can a surface be **flat** but *not* **smooth**?
4. What about an **even** surface? Is it one with no slope? Is it one with no bumps? Or both?

Comment: What is the difference between flat, 
straight, level and smooth? https://www.wonkeedonkeetools.co.uk/engineers-straight-edges/what-is-the-difference-between-flat-straight-level-and-smooth/

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Oh, that kinda answered most of my questions! Some remain unanswered though

Comment: This is more than a single question. You are more likely to receive a useful answer if you ask questions one at a time. The only way to answer all of them, though, is to consult multiple dictionaries and then to read and understand the usage examples. In order, the answers to your "more questions" are: Yes, Yes, Yes, Not necessarily, Probably, Not always.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally in English, as in other languages, certain words have many synonyms -- many of which as *similar*, but not necessarily the *same*.  The best way to learn the exact definitions is to notice what things the words are used with.

"Flat" refers to a surface that is generally *planar* (forming a plane in space), in that it does not *curve*.  A table is usually *flat*, a wall can be *flat*, and a television screen (nowadays) is *flat*.  An angled surface may be *flat* as long as it does not curve up or down.

Sometimes *flat* is used to mean *horizontal* as in "lie flat", but a horizontal surface is not necessarily a *flat* surface.

"Level", on the other hand, implies flatness but usually means perpendicular to the force of gravity.  A *level* surface is one which does not significantly curve up or down from side to side.  A tennis court is level (and also *flat*) because one side is not higher than the other.  A building should be constructed so that all the horizontal beams are *level*.  Something that is balanced over a fulcrum will be *level*.

"Smooth" relates to the surface quality.  A flat surface can be rough (bumpy to the touch) or smooth -- but if it is smooth and level, we might call it *perfectly* flat.  The surface of a ping-pong ball is *smooth*.  Someone's skin might be said to be *smooth* (if it is free from blemish).  An ice skating rink will be relatively smooth, as well as flat and level.

"Even" is a little more general. An even surface might be level, or smooth, or flat.  *Even* simply refers to the fact that the object appears *similar* from one side to the other  If you compare different parts of the surface there should be no marks or imperfections or significant differences in one part that there are not in another.  The surface doesn't have to be *smooth*, but if not, the texture should be *regular*.

An example of an even surface is a grassy sports field.  The grass makes it a *rough* surface, but there are minimal differences between one part of the surface and another.